# Applescript for tagging 4GB of PDF files

Tags: applescript, software-recommendation, automator, pdf

I've only recently come across automation world and realized that it could help me solve one big problem.

I've roughly 4 GB of PDF files in my computer, mostly from the university, they range from economics to philosophy and political science, in economics, they range across an almost infinite number of categories, the problem is that they are scattered all over the place.

So I figured that the tag system really would help, but to manually assign tags in 4 GB of PDF's is not going to be a pleasant task.

As far as I could figure out Automator isn't going to help because it seems it can't handle custom made tags, only the standard ones that come with Mac OS, so I turned to AppleScript, which I know virtually nothing.

One thing I discovered, I could, theoretically, write an AppleScript and attach it to folders so it'd scan its contents, looking for PDF’s based on their name and then based on that name assign the tag, but I have no idea how that AppleScript would look like.

Can anyone help? Share some code, or point me somewhere I can learn the basic to accomplish this "simple" task?

PS.: I came across an app called Hazel which it seems was designed to do that sort of thing, but I really would like to learn the basics of AppleScript, because I got the feeling that it pay off for a long time.

Comment: a good place to start would be: http://macscripter.net/

Comment: Junme, thanks, I've subscribed to their forum, I've been reading some stuff to try to figure out where I should begin.

Comment: Here's a good place to start, [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html), so as to start building an understanding of the subject matter before you jump into trying to code for the scenario you've presented.